# Finding solutions to a complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find all the fixed points of the function $g$ given by $g(z) = z^3 + z + 8i$.

Wasn't sure how to start this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a fixed point?

Comment: Yep I understand what a fixed point is I just don't know how I would answer this

Comment: If you write down the definition that should go straightforwardly.

Comment: Start with $g(z) = z$ (i.e., $g$ fixes $z$). Then solve for $z$. You do know how to find the cube roots of a complex number, right?

Comment: This makes sense now thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, $z$ is a fixed point of $g$, if $g(z)=z$. So, just write up and solve the equation:
$$z^3+z+8i=z$$
which will become
$$z^3=-8i$$
which can be solved e.g. graphically. (One solution seems $z=2i$..)

Comment: Thanks for this I understand how to solve it now